# Adding Conditional Step in Azure Pipeline for rollback of Kubernetes deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have an azure pipeline that deploys 2 Kubernetes deployments (manifest files) to AKS. I am not using HELM and kind of at intermediate level with AKS.

The tasks are something like this (for some reasons I am deploying 1 file at a time in separate tasks)

```
          - task: Kubernetes@1
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
            azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(serviceConnection)'
            azureResourceGroup: 'my-aks-rg'
            kubernetesCluster: 'my-aks'
            command: 'apply'
            arguments: '-f $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/manifest_1.yaml --record=true'             
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'


         - task: Kubernetes@1
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
            azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(serviceConnection)'
            azureResourceGroup: 'my-aks-rg'
            kubernetesCluster: 'my-aks'
            command: 'apply'
            arguments: '-f $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/manifest_2.yaml --record=true'             
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

Now the issue is, let's say if file 1 deployment passes and 2nd file fails then I have a half-deployed application and in case of any of these failures I want to gracefully roll-back all the deployments to previous versions.

I know roll back command for K8s.

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment/app1

kubectl rollout undo deployment/app2
```

If I add this command as CLI task then I am not sure how to detect that this CLI task only execute once something in pipeline has failed otherwise should just ignore and skip the cli task if all steps are passed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If deploying one file at a time in separate tasks.  This can be achieved through **Custom conditions**.  Specify the conditions under each stage, job.  In this scenario we can keep custom conditions under each stage.  On stage2 it will verify the step1 status and if any fails it will auto rollback the deployments.

```
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  displayName: Stage 1
  dependsOn: []
  condition: and(contains(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'), succeeded())
  jobs:
  - job: ShowVariables
    displayName: KubernetDeployment1
    steps:
     - task: Kubernetes@1
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
            azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(serviceConnection)'
            azureResourceGroup: 'my-aks-rg'
            kubernetesCluster: 'my-aks'
            command: 'apply'
            arguments: '-f $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/manifest_1.yaml --record=true'             
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'

- stage: Stage2
  displayName: stage 2
  
  jobs:
  - job: ShowVariables
   dependsOn: Stage1
    condition: eq(dependencies.Stage1.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes') 
    displayName: KubernetDeployment2
    steps:
    - task: Kubernetes@1
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
            azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(serviceConnection)'
            azureResourceGroup: 'my-aks-rg'
            kubernetesCluster: 'my-aks'
            command: 'apply'
            arguments: '-f $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/manifest_2.yaml --record=true'             
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

This portion will verify the stage1 status

```
dependsOn: Stage1
        condition: eq(dependencies.Stage1.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'], 'Yes')
```

Comment: Will it auto roll back? I mean lets say there are 3 steps. Step 1 passes, step 2 passes of Kubernetes Deploy then step 3 itself fails. So how will it go back to Cluster for previous steps and restore the previous pods? how is that automatically done?